# Getting Facebook information directly from Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

I was wondering if it is possible to extract the facebook account assigned to the windows phone, I would like to have access to the user name, picture and friends name, pictures (which are stored in the People of WP7).
This would be done in C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to access this information unfortunately.

Comment: closed platforms ftw :-(
There are several things I'd love to get at in Windows Phone 7... but cant

Comment: Ahh, that is a pain. It would be so much easier. Is there a way to automatically log the user in at all? Or do they always have to log in once and the app remember?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the name and photo of friends if the user has logged into their facebook account. You just can't get the account name and picture of the facebook login.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202972(v=vs.92).aspx